# Different snapshot from posting to Firebase from iPhone or from simulator swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, mkmapview, mkannotation

I'm getting the same snapshot twice from Firebase on a single notification and that causes the arrays I'm appending data to to get twice the entries. The  weird part is that it is true only from simulator. If I post the new notification from iPhone while running the app in simulator I get a correct snapshot in console, but if I post the new notification from simulator I get the snapshot twice. Can you see why I get twice the snapshots?
Here is the function I rewrote:

```
func displayAlerts(setCompletion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
    self.mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)
    MapArray.alertNotificationCoordinatesArray.removeAll()
    self.userAlertNotificationArray.removeAll()
    print("                     MapArray.alertNotificationCoordinatesArray before snapshot is: \(MapArray.alertNotificationCoordinatesArray)")
    print("                     self.userAlertNotificationArray before snapshot is: \(self.userAlertNotificationArray)")

    ref = Database.database().reference()

    databaseHandle = ref?.child("Continent").child("Europe").child("Country").child("Italy").child("Region").child("Emilia-Romagna").child("City").child("Bologna").child("Community").child("Alert Notifications").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in


        print("         snapshot is: \(snapshot)")
        guard let data = snapshot.value as? [String:String] else { return }
        guard let firebaseKey = snapshot.key as? String else { return }
        //                let date = data!["Date"]
        //                let time = data!["Time"]
        let dataLatitude = data["Latitude"]!
        let dataLongitude = data["Longitude"]!

        let type = data["Description"]!
        let id = Int(data["Id"]!)
        let doubledLatitude = Double(dataLatitude)
        let doubledLongitude = Double(dataLongitude)
        let recombinedCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: doubledLatitude!, longitude: doubledLongitude!)

        //            print("Firebase alerts posts retrieved")

        let userAlertAnnotation = UserAlert(type: type, coordinate: recombinedCoordinate, firebaseKey: firebaseKey, title: type,id: id!)

        self.userAlertNotificationArray.append(userAlertAnnotation)  // array of notifications coming from Firebase
        //            print("userAlertNotificationArray after retrieving from Firebase is : \(self.userAlertNotificationArray)")

        MapArray.alertNotificationCoordinatesArray.append(recombinedCoordinate) // array for checkig alerts on route


        print("                 MapArray.alertNotificationCoordinatesArray after snapshot is: \(MapArray.alertNotificationCoordinatesArray)")
        print("                     self.userAlertNotificationArray after snapshot is: \(self.userAlertNotificationArray)")
        setCompletion(true)
        self.mapView.addAnnotations(self.userAlertNotificationArray)
    })

}
```

And this is the print from console after one notification only to Firebase:

```
MapArray.alertNotificationCoordinatesArray at MapViewController viewDidLoad()  is[]

    self.userAlertNotificationArray before snapshot is: [] 


    alertNotificationCoordinatesArray at notifying is[]
    AlertPosted to Firebase
    self.userAlertNotificationArray after posting annotation is: []
    MapArray.alertNotificationCoordinatesArray after posting annotation is: []
         snapshot is: Snap (-LZq2J1n59Ps-yPV3-9j) {
    Description = "Lavori in corso";
    Id = 0;
    Latitude = "44.5075";
    Longitude = "11.3514";
}
                 MapArray.alertNotificationCoordinatesArray after snapshot is: [__C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 44.5075, longitude: 11.3514)]
                     self.userAlertNotificationArray after snapshot is: [<fix_it_Cloud_Biking.UserAlert: 0x600003610180>]
    %%%%%%%   data retrieving is finished
CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 44.5075, longitude: 11.3514)
                     MapArray.alertNotificationCoordinatesArray before snapshot is: []
                     self.userAlertNotificationArray before snapshot is: []
         snapshot is: Snap (-LZq2J1n59Ps-yPV3-9j) {
    Description = "Lavori in corso";
    Id = 0;
    Latitude = "44.5075";
    Longitude = "11.3514";
}
                 MapArray.alertNotificationCoordinatesArray after snapshot is: [__C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 44.5075, longitude: 11.3514)]
                     self.userAlertNotificationArray after snapshot is: [<fix_it_Cloud_Biking.UserAlert: 0x600003674960>]
    %%%%%%%   data retrieving is finished
```

as you can see at `viewDidLoad' the array is empty, but after notifying once it has 2 entries in it..
Thank you very much as usual guys.

Comment: Which function are you actually using in your code: displayAlerts() or displayAlerts2()?

Comment: @schtipoun originally `displayAlerts()`but I tried to use a `for in` loop so I wrote `displayAlerts2()`thinking that the loop would solve the duplicates problem but it didn't.

Comment: And I assume that your coordinates are all different in your Firebase Database? And where are your prints coming from in your code because I can't see any print with `alertNotificationCoordinatesArray at notifying is` or with just the array

Comment: @schtipoun In Firebase Notifications get posted correctly, only once. The print comes from the button's action that starts the notification process. The array gets populated only in the `displayAlerts()`function. that's why I don't get why it gets a multiple append..

Comment: Oh, I got it, you get multiple values in your array when you would want to have only one, right? Is it not because you use `observe` rather than `observeSingleEvent`?

Comment: @schtipoun i use .observe because i need to get notified when new annotations get added from users.  Anyways.. it should only append once per annotation right?

Comment: No I think it's the normal behaviour, when something happens on the node you're watching, it adds the same value to the array. In the notification process, is there anything else than the value happening on this node? (that could explain the fact that it's added multiple times)

Comment: @schtipoun I think I see where the problem is. As I understood .observe would get all the Childs once, and than if a new child gets added I get a snapshot with only that value. So  when I start the app fresh I  call `display Alerts() `in `viewDidLoad' , it gets all the notifications and that's ok. The problem is that when I make a new notification I get everything again in the snapshot, not only the one I just added. That's what gets the mess in my map.

Comment: Probably yes :)

Comment: Ok, I checked and it works as I said, I only get snapshot with newer notification while I'm in `MapView` but the whole notifications in the node when I first load `MapView` so If I add the notification to the map there it will keep adding the same over and over. I might clear the map at the beginning of the function, and then on completion add the whole array at once. that I think would fix the doubles.

Comment: My only concern now is the size of the snapshot, as it will get giant and costly..if I have to redownload all the node every time I open `MapView'. any advise on that side?

Comment: What I usually do is to "isolate" the data I need for a snapshot in a specific node and then put the other data in an another node to have the equivalent of hot and cold data.

Comment: @schtipoun I'm rewriting the function, see my edits to new explanation please, It doesn't make any sense to me so far.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189259/discussion-between-vincenzo-and-schtipoun).